# Python MIP Library - How to impose the binary variable constraints effectively

Tags: python, optimization, constraints

Thank you so much for your kindness to read this post and share your valuable insights with me.

I have recently tried to apply Python MIP library to construct a simulated portfolio. The objective function is to maximize the portfolio return - sum of weight i x asset return i. The constraints include two: 1. Number of investments in North America should be between 45 and 39, 2. Number of investments in EU should be between 12 and 9.

But the MIP library results in the asset weights that violate the two constraints. Please see the orange highlighted parts in the snapshot.
[The resulting weights Violate the two constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC9ei.png)

I used the following code for imposing the constraints. na_dum (eu_dum)  is a dummy variable takes one if investments belong to North America (Europe), otherwise 0 :

```
na_bool = [ m.add_var(var_type=BINARY) for i in range(numSecurities) ] 
eu_bool = [ m.add_var(var_type=BINARY) for i in range(numSecurities) ] 
m += xsum(weights[i] * na_dum[i] for i in range(numSecurities))<=na_sumweight_upper 
m += xsum(weights[i] * na_dum[i] for i in range(numSecurities))>=na_sumweight_lower 
m += xsum(weights[i] * eu_dum[i] for i in range(numSecurities))<=eu_sumweight_upper 
m += xsum(weights[i] * eu_dum[i] for i in range(numSecurities))>=eu_sumweight_lower
```

I would much appreciate if you can tell me how to address the issue and impose the two constraints effectively.

I would much appreciate if you can tell me how to address the issue and impose the two constraints effectively.